# Automatically reorganising attributes in Android XML files

Tags: android, xml

In many of my layout files, I have a different order of XML attributes and I would like to reorder them, so that e.g. `android:id=""` be always the first and `android:layout_below=""` would always be the last (choosing priorities for all the other attributes as well).

Is there any tool I could use to do this automatically? 
I am working on Eclipse.

Comment: use this to format your code `ctrl+shift+f` sorry i don't know for what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press `ctrl+shift+f` to reorganising in xml layout